# Workaround replace Applet scenario

Tags: java, applet, activex

Today I'm using an applet to modify client-side information, considering the new browsers i have to found out a new workaround to continue modifying file and execute windows command at client-side because some browser are suspending the applet execution.

Any ideia for solution that has allow windows command execution and access file at client side like Activex ?

Comment: You are listing exactly why applets have that low reputation.

Comment: In my administrative solution i have to change some information and execute client side commands, today i use signed.

Answer (score 0):

Applets have always been sitting between webapps and desktop apps. In that sense, what you want to achieve is **exactly** what every hacker in the world wants to achieve, that is gain access to your computer from a browser. And I think it would fair to say that for that reason, applets are dying and are not coming back from the dead anytime soon.

But unfortunatly some functionalities **need** applets to run, and what you can do really depends on those functionalities.

### Statu-quo

They are still working in IE (not Edge), Firefox and Safari. If you **control your clients environment** you can maybe still use them **as is**. But for how long ?

### Move to Server

You move your functionalities on the server. In your case, it would probably mean upload files on the server, execute your commands there and send the file back on the client. Javascript and HTML 5 can certainly help here improve the overall user experience.

### Move to Desktop

If you are doing some pretty intensive stuff on the client (processing multiple files, accessing resources that cannot be used from a browser, etc), you should consider regrouping this into a desktop app. You can even launch your app from a browser and sends some parameters to it by registering a [Custom Protocol Handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx), *a la iTunes*. Again, this is certainly not an easy replacement, as functionalities will often be spread out between the desktop app and the web app, which makes for some interesting *scratch head* moments trying to link the 2.